# Does proguard remove unused classes in android.jar?

Tags: android, proguard

Suppose i am developing an application using android api 16, my app will include android.jar. I would be importing few classes from the jar file.

I would enable proguard in release mode by configuring proguard. Does proguard remove unused classes in android.jar also?

Edit:

properties file for my project

android.library.reference.1=../actionbarsherlock

So does proguard remove unused classes from my library project included when packaging everything to .apk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proguard does NOT remove anything from libraries. See the diagram and quote from the [Proguard website.](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/introduction.html)

> ProGuard requires the library jars (or wars, ears, zips, or
>   directories) of the input jars to be specified. These are essentially
>   the libraries that you would need for compiling the code. ProGuard
>   uses them to reconstruct the class dependencies that are necessary for
>   proper processing. **The library jars themselves always remain
>   unchanged.** You should still put them in the class path of your final
>   application.

Comment: so what happens if everything is packaged to .apk and i have enabled proguard by configuring it. Does my .apk file have all unused classes?

Comment: Proguard and packaging to .apk are two different things. Proguard will only remove unused classes from what you tell it is source code and what it thinks can be removed unless you tell it not to remove it. As it says on the website it does not touch the library jars

Answer (score 0):

Android.jar would be referenced as a library jar (-libraryjars, see [Proguard documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html)) as opposed to an input jar. That means it would not be included in the output APK anyway. After all you don't want to redistribute the Android system libraries along with your app.

Comment: @ddevconsole the simple is no? Proguard removes unused classes of external libraries  if included.